# Firebase does not load image only on one device

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app is already deployed using firebase and the images does not load and it says this error. I'm using Google Chrome and even if I'll use incognito, it still won't load

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

However, this only happens on my device. If I'll use my phone or other devices, then, the images would just load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not particularly a Firebase issue, but an issue with the device not being able to resolve the DNS. The following are some common solutions:

1. Restart the router
2. Clear your browsing data
3. Clear your device DNS cache

There are some resources here:

- https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-name-not-resolved-error/
- https://theitbros.com/err-name-not-resolved/
- https://tunecomp.net/err_name_not_resolved-fix-dns-error/
- https://solutionbay.com/solutions/how-to-fix-errnamenotresolved-windows-mac-os-android-ios